# Send form (AJAX) in android and receive JSON response

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, json

The idea is duplicate on android this web http://www.telekino.com.ar/ In the site there is a form to check if your lottery ticket won

[image]

According to other Post, the site uses the ajax to contact the webservice and get the data.

I dont know where start, the only step I can do is the layout. ( Three EditText for the three values needed to send the form, and one button to start the process) then I am lost. How i continue? What I need to use to send this values and receive the  response.?

Is possible to duplicate on the app this request?

Comment: Do you know what ajax send to the webservice ? This can be done using `JSONObject` and `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: You code is required to understand what you have done.

Comment: The only code i wrote was The layout.  I dont know where start whit the java code.

Comment: @AgustinScalisi, if you only know how to make the layout, the answer to your question will be very long. That includes button onclick listener, getting the text from EditText, handling the http request on the background, creating JSONObject and more.

Comment: This is to get you started. The form you're referring to will send get request to `telekino.com.ar/cupones/control/{Sorteo}/{Número de Cartón}/{Algoritmo}.json`

Comment: Thats help! yes, I will start with that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a http request here and in my success method I get a response saved in the variable "data".

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http:/****.**/api/gebruikers?email=' + $scope.email + '&wachtwoord=' + $scope.wachtwoord }).success(function (data) {
                // variable "data" is the JSON response I recieve, it is a JSON string.

            });
```